# Is it better to remote connect to a desktop or invest in a better laptop?

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop

I want to build a Desktop computer mainly using it for work and classes. But the problem is that it is not portable. Would accessing it remotely be a viable option or should I just invest in a better laptop?

For example I would be using it to run virtual machines and development tools.

Comment: This really depends on your individual situation.  I'd never rely on remote desktop stuff myself because I do a lot of work at places that have sketchy / no Internet connections.  If you have regular access to good Internet at the places you work though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using a remote desktop is that you will be at the mercy of your network speed and connection.

If portability is a feature you are looking then invest in a decent laptop. You can still connect it to an external display, keyboard and mouse when you are at home for a desktop experience.